# Select all from TWO tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to select all the results from a table A and all results from table B 
I used this Request:

```
$request_public_imgs = $BDD-> query("SELECT * FROM images_public ");
    UNION("SELECT * FROM images_users  WHERE img_kind='PublicImg' ")
    ;
```

But I receive this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function UNION()

Comment: `SELECT * FROM images_users,images_public WHERE  images_users.img_kind='PublicImg'` returns no result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your SQL command as a single piece :

```
$request_public_imgs = $BDD-> query("SELECT id, field1, .. FROM images_public 
   UNION SELECT id, field1, .. FROM images_users  WHERE img_kind='PublicImg' ") ;
```

You should select precise field and not using * for performance matter.
Adrien

Comment: Performance is a good reason to avoid select *, but is far from the best reason.  How about if column orders change in the result set or table?

Comment: Thank u ^^ This is better than the * FOR ME cause i have different columns

Answer (score 3):

`UNION` is a `MySQL` function, hence you need to put it inside the `query()`:

```
$request_public_imgs = $BDD-> query("
SELECT * FROM images_public
    UNION
SELECT * FROM images_users  WHERE img_kind='PublicImg' ");
```

More generally, all the queries will work like:

```
$request_public_imgs = $BDD-> query("YOUR_MYSQL_QUERY");
```

Note that the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function UNION()` was warning about `UNION` not being a function of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$request_public_imgs = $BDD-> query("SELECT * FROM images_public 
    UNION SELECT * FROM images_users  WHERE img_kind='PublicImg' ")
    ;
```